# ios add custom property to uitableviewcell button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have 2 table in single view. `table_1` and `table_2` with custom cell

```
customCell *cell = (customCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

having two buttons edit and delete.
and added target method for `editBtn`:

```
[cell.btnEdit addTarget:self action:@selector(editBtnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

When I click on edit button, I want to know which table's cell button it is. For that, I want to give custom attribute like "tabName" to edit button.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try using a category with Associative References instead. It is much cleaner and will work on all instances of UIButton.

UIButton+Property.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UIButton(Property)

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSObject *property;

@end
```

UIButton+Property.m

```
#import "UIButton+Property.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIButton(Property)

static char UIB_PROPERTY_KEY;

@dynamic property;

-(void)setProperty:(NSObject *)property
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &UIB_PROPERTY_KEY, property,     
    OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

-(NSObject*)property
{
    return (NSObject*)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &UIB_PROPERTY_KEY);
}

@end
```

/Example usage

```
#import "UIButton+Property.h"
```

...

```
UIButton *button1 = [UIButton     
buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button1.property = @"HELLO";
NSLog(@"Property %@", button1.property);
button1.property = nil;
NSLog(@"Property %@", button1.property);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, i think this will help you easily.

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    customCell *cell = (customCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    [cell.btnEdit addTarget:self action:@selector(editBtnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    objc_setAssociatedObject(cell.btnEdit, @"idxPath", indexPath, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
    if(tableView == table_1)
    {
        cell.btnEdit.tag = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.btnEdit.tag = 2;
    }
    return cell;
}
- (void)editBtnClick:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = objc_getAssociatedObject(sender, @"idxPath");
    if (sender.tag == 1)
    {
        //handle first table view edit button event
    }
    else
    {
        //handle second table view edit button event
    }
}
```

Comment: i have tried this but i have two array array1 and array2 for each table.so i also need indexpath.row for each row so i need another property @Jayesh Thanki